# Как задать несколько команд через оператор switch

Tags: c++, arduino, switch

```
switch (val)
{
case 1 :
    break;
}
```

Нужно что бы в случае, если `val == 1`, выполнялось следующее:

```
analogWrite(BwdPin_A,LOW);
analogWrite(FwdPin_A,MaxSpd);
delay(5000);
analogWrite(FwdPin_A,LOW);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это записать?

Comment: Написать между `case 1:` и `break;` все эти команды, нет?

Comment: а чем не устраивает простая if ?

Answer (score 3):

Ну вроде так:

```
switch(val) {
  case 1:
    analogWrite(BwdPin_A,LOW);
    analogWrite(FwdPin_A,MaxSpd);
    delay(5000);
    analogWrite(FwdPin_A,LOW);
    break;
}
```

Comment: почему минус-то?

Comment: Какой минус-то? И не проще просто if(val == 1) использовать?